# React doesn't update the state on second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, state

I’m creating a simple react app where users click on a specific area on a map and get a carousel with images of products from that area. The problem is that on the first click the state updates fine and the products get displayed but on every second click they don't, third click works fine. I tried to clear the state first with each new click, but it doesn't work.  I’ve heard that it might be connected to the asynchronicity of useState, but I’m not sure how to make it work in this case.

**App component** with carousel products state:

```
const App = () => {
  const [openCarousel, setOpenCarousel] = useState(false);
  const [carouselProducts, setCarouselProducts] = useState([]);

  const toggleCarousel = () => setOpenCarousel(!openCarousel);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Map open={toggleCarousel} setProducts={setCarouselProducts} />
      <main>
        <Container>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Route exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      {openCarousel && (
        <MultiCarousel
          products={carouselProd}
          close={toggleCarousel}
          setProducts={setCarouselProducts}
        />
      )}
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Map component** with 3 map fields to click. The clicked() function should clear the previous state, call setDisplayed() to set the new state and then call open() to open the carousel.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import products from "../products.js";

const Map = ({ setProducts, open }) => {

  const setDisplayed = (e) => {
    let selectedProducts = [];
    let selectedProdSeries = "";
    let area = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    switch (area) {
     case "Podlachian":
        selectedProdSeries = "first";
        break;
      case "Lublin":
        selectedProdSeries = "second";
        break;
      case "Subcarpathian":
        selectedProdSeries = "third";
        break;
      default:
        selectedProdSeries = "";
    }

    let selectedSeries = products.filter(
      (product) => product.series === selectedProdSeries
    );
    selectedProducts = selectedSeries;
    setProducts(selectedProducts);

    console.log(selectedProdSeries);
  };

  const clicked = (e) => {
     setProducts([]);
    setDisplayed(e);
    open();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-map-container">
        <div className="mapdiv">
          <div className="svg-div">
            <svg
              baseProfile="tiny"
              fill="#7c7c7c"
              stroke="#ffffff"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              version="1.2"
              viewBox="0 0 1000 948"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M902.7 429.6l-0.8 0.5-1.8"
                id="POL3150"
                name="Podlachian"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  clicked(e);
                }}
              ></path>
              <path
                d="M902.7 429.6l0.7 0.6 1.1 1.6 0.3 2.1-0.8 2.9 2.3 1.5 7.1 1.9 "
                id="POL3151"
                name="Lublin"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  clicked(e);
                }}
              ></path>
              <path
                d="M950.7 741.8l-1.4 2.2-7.9 "
                id="POL3152"
                name="Subcarpathian"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  clicked(e);
                }}
              ></path>
            
              <circle cx="117.2" cy="233.1" id="0"></circle>
              <circle cx="611.2" cy="696.4" id="1"></circle>
              <circle cx="678" cy="712.1" id="2"></circle>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

Map.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: You are using a toggle for the openCarousel state. If the user clicks on an item in the map, the openCarousel will first be set to true but on a second click on the map, it will be toggled to false.

Comment: `MultiCarousel` should only be shown when there is data. What you are doing is treating it like a button to toggle on and off with the use of boolean values in the state of `openCarousel`.

Comment: @shilch Yes, obviously that was the case, thank you so much. I feel so dumb right now.